# Integral is Zero for all Measurable Sets and $f=0$ Almost Everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $f \in L^1(\mu)$ and $\displaystyle \int_E f \, d \mu = 0$ for every $E \in \frak{M}$. Then $f=0$ a.e. on $X$.

I have the following theorem available to use:

> Suppose that $f : X \to [0,\infty]$ is measurable, $E \in \frak{M}$ and $\displaystyle \int_E f \, d \mu = 0$. Then $f = 0$ a.e. on $E$.

Here is my proof of the first theorem. Suppose that $f = u + iv \in L^1(\mu)$. Then $u,v \in L^1(\mu)$. Furthermore,

$$0 = \int_E f \, d \mu = \int_E u \, d \mu + i \int_E v \, d \mu$$

implies $ \int_E u \, d \mu = 0 = \int_E v \, d \mu$ for every $E \in \frak{M}$. Because of $u$ and $v$ are complex measurable, $E = \{x \in X \mid u(x) \ge 0 \}$ is measurable and therefore $\int_E u \, d \mu =0$. Since $u$ is nonnegative over $E$, the above theorem applies, which means there exists a set $N_1 \subseteq E$ of zero measure such that $u \neq 0$ on $N_1$. Similarly, we can obtain a set $N_2$ of zero measure over which $v \neq 0$. Therefore $\mu (N_1 \cup N_2) = 0$ and if $x \in X-(N_1 \cup N_2) = (X - N_1 ) \cap (X-N_2)$, then $x \notin N_1 \cap N_2$ and therefore $u=0=v$ which implies $f(x)=0$. Thus $f=0$ a.e. on $X- (N_1 \cup N_2)$ and $N_1 \cup N_2$ is of zero measure.

Does this sound right? Something seems off, but I can't spot it. Hopefully whatever the issue is it can be easily fixed.

Comment: If $\mu E = 0$ for all measurable sets, then $\mu \{ x | f(x) \neq 0 \}$ is necessarily zero and hence $f=0$ ae. [$\mu$]. It is also true that $f=42$ ae. [$\mu$].

Comment: @copper.hat I fixed the error in the statement of the theorem

Comment: You have the right idea, but you need to fix some minor things. You have shown that the set $\{x | u(x) \ge 0 \}$ is null, you need to show that the negative side is null and then take the union to get $N_1$. Also, $N_1$ is a null set **containing** $\{ x | u(x) \geq 0 \}$, your statement above describes $N_1$ as being **contained** in this set.